# Imagem no TSpeedButton com TImageList

Tags: delphi, delphi-10, firemonkey

Saudações a todos!

Estou começando a desenvolver em Delphi 10 Seattle, antes utilizava o Delphi 7. Estou tentando criar uma barra de ferramentas, estou utilizando o TToolbar com um TActionList, TSpeedButtons e TImageList. Estou utilizando imagens quadradas com 32px, mas quando escolho a imagem, pelo ImageIndex, no TSpeedButton, a imagem fica com um tamanho menor que 32px, acho que fica com 16px.

Como eu posso definir o tamanho da imagem no TSpeedButton utilizando um TImageList ?

Editado em 08/06/2016 para inclusão de código de exemplo
Unit:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants,
  FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Dialogs;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    SpeedButton1: TSpeedButton;
    ImageList1: TImageList;
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}

end.
```

DFM

```
object Form1: TForm1
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Form1'
  ClientHeight = 231
  ClientWidth = 421
  FormFactor.Width = 320
  FormFactor.Height = 480
  FormFactor.Devices = [Desktop]
  DesignerMasterStyle = 0
  object SpeedButton1: TSpeedButton
    Images = ImageList1
    ImageIndex = 0
    Position.X = 156.000000000000000000
    Position.Y = 32.000000000000000000
    Size.Width = 117.000000000000000000
    Size.Height = 22.000000000000000000
    Size.PlatformDefault = False
    Text = 'SpeedButton1'
  end
  object ImageList1: TImageList
    Source = <
      item
        MultiResBitmap = <
          item
            Scale = 2.000000000000000000
            Width = 32
            Height = 32
            PNG = {
              89504E470D0A1A0A0000000D4948445200000020000000200806000000737A7A
              F4000000017352474200AECE1CE90000000467414D410000B18F0BFC61050000
              072E4944415458479D576D6C5465167E66EEDCF96AE9509CB6CC143A8084EFF8
              B16EAA488040502306297E60F4871A51134D8C89C15D5D77FF18D8FD21313126
              9BCD66FFEC8FFDB1648DA001242E6E9664356A549482424BDB99964E3F66DA4E
              A79DAF3B77669FF3CEDC6166182AF121CFEDE53DE73DE7BCE73DEFB9EFD87093
              E87E052DBE763C0F0DCF146DB8AD3C0C1B2D582C98F8C151C4DFE351FCEDABF7
              315B5659103F17806DC741ACB22DC1318F139BB66ED88A951D212CF707502CE4
              30974B209D9D21134864A6313C19C5442281683C837C1EBDD9247AFE731803B4
              532C99BB1E0B05A0ED3A8C3FBB5C78F1A5075FC396755B306B8CC0C00C67E550
              2C166072C9A6693218206764119F9D4034368048EC274426E6301A074C037F3D
              F5065EA63DB364B616370A40DFF94784EF59FBABC01F1E791749F4235588E0EA
              E40F189FBA80786200998CA9D2AEC0BF2E5D87CFBB1C2DCDB7C2ED08E2CAE8B7
              B838729E7380D939444FFE16216A1AA509D7D028007DFB210CBD70DFD3C19EEE
              27305D3887B1E9F33877F928B24601767B6952C57915549EF9D01D0E74F87630
              434E7C3BF06F8CC6B2B81AC3E8A9DF6005356A82A837A3EF3A84C8933B1E5DBA
              FBD70F21A30DA277F0430C8DF642D3003BB52DC7E2AC58DE595584A557051917
              D162EF6AB47AEFC2D7FD2710E6960C8F61ECF49BE8A2A81204CD56A0ED7A1B7F
              D9B86AE5B6C7B7EC47D17D15DFF5FD1323133F810B82262B172F24B71C793E98
              109865672A88B2DC7A4F1B53D44DE2D68E9D984DF5633E6B3607EF45F0CA6738
              414D153ECD2AD8EE3E80352E2F0EECDFF2186C9E299C1F3CCE22EAABACDC82AC
              4E9CEFD9700CAF6E2D2ACABB8C5919B120F366D311CCA4BFC11D2B77A1B38DB5
              E2C101F145B1B26A05A0B7ACC207F7DFB90DCD8B80A9641FC2E3E74BCE454354
              CB640F50AB0EB5EE95790AF2AE3251A56751E6CFA4FBA139B258D3B911413FB7
              86BE28D5C95200CBEF85DFE9C2FAF5CB43F078ECF87EF06843E716650BEAA1C6
              1AE80A6DB43331F75F74F937A1CD6783D38DF5E293521580B67A079E5BDBD9A9
              F67A7CE62272791E31A98E06C62AAC47239D32A51E8CA281AC19455B4B08ADCC
              F21AFAA4544A0B4EDD8BA7962C6A82DBEDC218035045448140B6B5C08745ABC2
              EB216322ABD12D8914C4DE9C3104BFAF0B4D6EC0419F1C724A006EBB8EF5BE26
              3BBCEE262458349232992169954ACFB287A5AB986DB0073256A343CA5CA52ADE
              C98C11456BF3521580C62DE7A89B4987107933AD569065EF94BC48F4AADAD71D
              43C877ADE06E8437791AEA114E1CC7C7977AA0D39EC460F09F839E55DE4BEA8E
              F25A19353F2C7933AFD22F23956ABF09E73782CCBDEE74D44225BBD4347249E4
              8DFC35A5EB17F4CBB180AD520064D6287DD9AC0C48687214258DBF1432576C58
              35D520036AA87DF7118C6F60877EE0CE273134FF2FA6CD5002A964A903D32A26
              A25427DCF3CDB5CBFAD31736B8C459D989F894BD964D968E28DA0E567BD0BD0F
              9F7D7F141723C0C983E810BDA29941DF5C06882546E075042AD14A23D259A22E
              F62C4F15E5FFF568A42373AB9B995B0B607A6E0CF3F4253E395A14719E631FA7
              3838911846B36345CD96C95C5981C5EA1E510D1913598D6E495441136D4FCE44
              5400E29343790920D3FB11FE319D04269361B81080AEE90DFB7A0DEBD148A74C
              B1E5A04DB11DA30FF1253E29CD4800B94404E3B9140626678A08C77BD1EEDCBE
              60002AAD75B8D1774328B6FCB419A16DF121BEC427A53999C692C2FC8F1FE155
              B9C35DBE7A0166CE85C58ED528D41912AAD3418667AF9D0E7997B19A6A2F536C
              F8C4166DF6D3B6F8105F94CE93A6A8099C6460DBEB782FB8027BD72E73E19EB5
              3D8817BE40D28C54BED9162AA7A35C2C1AAD58D55E0D11376B5D5862DF8C2F2F
              1DC3A5912C468770FCEC3B2A802899936F9E404E9919FE1CE7966DC57E9BDDF4
              A67261ACBE6527AD6691C69452AAF40852526E1DB3CAA5A54CB57D1C6FD17825
              B377E39B2B2778654F63620AF1336FE3594AC5394B9173E551866C45A1FF0C4E
              F9BBD1C3ABB7779617894E5F377CCE10B58799CE7237A003751AAA58A9191594
              8E76C74E6846079D9F54CE2351C44EFF0E7BA8314CCA8F1665AC3A00C9588E34
              7867FBA4FD6EECE31DCE9348F5C165F76059D37678B45BE8A4C84052DCBC8272
              6A51B7E9F0DA97A155BB1DADE8E6757C80179BFF61306A62228EA9D36FE161DA
              1E22259DECF92548CCF5600B51B795D0B683F8BD2F808782F4DBB6D806FFA210
              6F345DFCA40678AC9C35FDC234736C32514CB2BCE5A849B54BC125A23871F608
              0E51254CC6C805AFE5162488567269E00E6CDAF8280E7BBC58213719F996ABEF
              39535D0D69D7D2608472CED3290C5DF8006F45CFA197E231729ABCA91F261664
              7BBC24D78F36AF1F1D1BF7614F6B10F739166165CDF205B4944F62707A149F5E
              F8909D35A6CE397F178179408A941ABB0E0B052010B964430269225B481FE921
              EB72A08A2A4D2648293239E7E258565D1F6E053F1740352423D22FB801EA1655
              3F579C4871C9F192626EB8E25A00FF070AD8D2DC0DBED52F0000000049454E44
              AE426082}
            FileName = 'D:\Documentos\Imagens\Icones Pesquisar\32x32\add.png'
          end>
        Name = 'add'
      end>
    Destination = <
      item
        Layers = <
          item
            Name = 'add'
            SourceRect.Right = 32.000000000000000000
            SourceRect.Bottom = 32.000000000000000000
          end>
      end>
    Left = 88
    Top = 20
  end
end
```

No exemplo acima estou usando apenas o TSpeedButton e o TImageList.

Obrigado!

Deus nos abençoe!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consultei fóruns e continuei pesquisando na internet e estou postando uma opção para resolver o problema.

O tamanho da imagem no TSpeedButton é definido através de uma folha de estilo (stylesheet), e apenas por esta opção foi possível alterá-lo.

Como alterar:

Primeiro **clique** com o **botão Direito** em qualquer TSpeedButton do seu formulário, e escolha a opção **Edit Default Style...**.

[image: clique com o botão Direito em qualquer TSpeedButton do seu formulário, e escolha a opção Edit Default Style...]

No modo de edição de estilo, no painel **Structure** localize e selecione a opção **glyphstyle: TGlyph**.
No **Object Inspector**, **procure** por **size**.
Note que a **altura(Height)** e a **Largura(Width)** vão estar com o valor de 16 (pixels), altere seus valores para **32** ou o tamanho que desejar.

[image]

Quando terminar clique no botão Apply and Close.

Feito isso, todos os TSpeedButtons vão apresentar as imagens com 32px ou no tamanho que você definir.

**Observação:**
O tamanho do TSpeedButton deve comportar o tamanho da imagem que você definiu, ou ela será redimensionada.

Abraços e obrigado a todos pela ajuda!

Answer (score 2):

Digamos que temos SpeedButton1 (TSpeedButton) e ImageList1 (TImageList)

O tamanho da imagem estará definida nas propriedades do TImageList, Height e Width, se você atribuir 32 e 32 respectivamente e só após adicionar uma imagem ao ImageList do tamanho de 32px e também o tamanho do SpeedButton for superior ou igual a 32px de lado o tamanho da imagem mostrada será de 32px.

Caso você adicione a imagem antes de definir essas medidas acontecerá que a imagem ficará menor que o desejado.

Para você atribuir uma imagem do ImageList para o SpeedButton basta colocar o seguinte código...

```
ImageList1.GetBitmap(0, SpeedButton1.Glyph);
```

Sendo 0 o índice da imagem em ImageList1.

Comment: Obrigado @cava pela ajuda. No TImageList foi definido o tamanho de 32px para altura e largura no momento que insiro as imagens, e também depois quando defino suas ordens(elas vem por padrão com 16px), mas mesmo feito isto não resolveu o problema. Não fiz a adição através de código, fiz direto pelo componente.